# Warning in Azure Devops Release Pipeline for SQL DB Deploy task: "The names of some imported commands from the module 'SqlPS'..."

Tags: azure-devops

I've created a very simple Release Pipeline in Azure DevOps using the "IIS website and SQL database deployment" template. It works as expected -- the website and database are both updated successfully on the on-prem IIS/MSSQL host, but I'm faced with this warning in the "SQL DB Deploy" task:

```
##[section]Starting: SQL DB Deploy
==============================================================================
Task         : SQL Server database deploy
Description  : Deploy a SQL Server database using DACPAC or SQL scripts
Version      : 0.3.23
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-dacpac-deployment-on-machine-group
==============================================================================
##[warning]The names of some imported commands from the module 'SqlPS' include unapproved verbs that might make them less discoverable. To find the commands with unapproved verbs, run the Import-Module command again with the Verbose parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.
##[section]Finishing: SQL DB Deploy
```

I tried adding `-DisableNameChecking` to the "Additional Arguments" section of the task, but the warning persisted and was followed by an error and failure:

```
##[error]A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DisableNameChecking'.
```

I am one of those people who likes to only see warnings that mean something, so I know to take a closer look... which means I need to handle this somehow. Not seeing a whole lot of options. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning means there are some cmdlets that do not conform to the PowerShell naming convention, but the module and its containing cmdlets are still all loaded into your host.

You can avoid this error by including the `-DisableNameChecking` parameter to the **Import-Module cmdlet** when you import the SQLPS module. You tried adding `-DisableNameChecking` to the "Additional Arguments" section of the `SQL DB Deploy` task, but this argument is adding additional **SqlPackage.exe** arguments, that's why you can not get it working.

[image]

You can check the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroupV0/README.md) of this task, and you can find there is no `-DisableNameChecking` parameter the Import-SqlPs Module:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroupV0/Utility.ps1

If you really want to disable the warning, I'm afraid there is no default way, unless you customize the task.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is much you could do personally if you want to continue to use this task.  You could raise an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/) and they might include an update to pass `-DisableNameChecking` to the import-module call.  It has not real impact on the execution of the task, just that the function name in the module doesn't conform to the PS standard.

If it bothers you so much, you could probably fork the open-source task, disable the name-checking, and publish your own task.